# Getting an invalid argument error while trying to download file from a server in my app

Tags: android

I am trying to get a file from the server and store it in the sd card in my app. I am getting an invalid argument error.

Please see the attached code and logcat below. Kindly help

Also, is there any better way to do this. I frequently get socket timeout exception as well

```
File file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null),values);

                URL url = new URL("http://abcd.com/edmuploads/"+values);
                URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setReadTimeout(7000);
                urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(7000);

                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedInputStream bufferinstream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);

                ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(5000);
                int current = 0;
                while((current = bufferinstream.read()) != -1){
                    baf.append((byte) current);
                }

//This is where I am getting an invalid  argument error. The line number 560 as mentioned in the logs below
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file, false); 

                    fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
                    fos.flush();
                    fos.close();
```

Log cat

```
08-06 10:15:37.089: W/System.err(11448): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.veleztechnologies.eldicciomalopremium/files/1375701341.3gp
08-06 10:15:37.089: W/System.err(11448):  (Invalid argument)
08-06 10:15:37.099: W/System.err(11448):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSFileSystem.open(Native Method)
08-06 10:15:37.099: W/System.err(11448):    at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedFileSystem.open(BlockGuard.java:232)
08-06 10:15:37.099: W/System.err(11448):    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:94)
08-06 10:15:37.099: W/System.err(11448):    at com.veleztechnologies.eldicciomalopremium.WordListActivity.getFileList(WordListActivity.java:560)
```

Comment: the file name of filepath you provides is not matched hence it results in it

Comment: Thanks Tony. But I did not get you. To what should the filepath match? What changes should I do in the code to match the file path?

Comment: /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/com.veleztechnologies.eldicciomalopremium/files/1375701341.3gp
08-06 10:15:37.089: W/System.err(11448):  (Invalid argument)

Comment: the above line shows that in the filepath /files/1375701‌​341.3gp  is not existed ..

Comment: you have to check before the file receive progress whether the file is there or not

Comment: yes..but that is the file I am downloading from the server to my sdcard. So, it should not exist before the download process..

Comment: Will this FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file, false); not overwrite and create a new file if it already exists?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34888/discussion-between-tony-stark-and-ambit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution to this. Was a problem with special character in the filename. There was a newline character at the end of the filename, which was appended by mistake, when the file was created in the first place. Removing that fixed this.Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can't write to files that don't exist in this case. Instead, use:

```
if(!file.exists()) {
    file.createNewFile();
}
```

EDIT: as for better methods for downloading files, this is what I use:

```
URL website = new URL("http://url");
ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("information.html");
fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
```

For the FileOutputStream, you might need to use an absolute path.

Comment: Thanks. But as per the documentation, should this FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file, false);  not overwrite and create a new file if it already exists

Comment: No, it only says "don't append to the file". My code checks if the file exists, and if not, it creates a new one. Also, the docs say "throws FileNotFoundException," so what I said still applies.

Comment: I tried this. But now I am getting an invalid argument error at file.createNewFile() line

08-06 10:39:39.679: W/System.err(11531): java.io.IOException: Invalid argument
08-06 10:39:39.689: W/System.err(11531):  at java.io.File.createNewFileImpl(Native Method)
08-06 10:39:39.689: W/System.err(11531):  at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1257)
08-06 10:39:39.699: W/System.err(11531):  at com.veleztechnologies.eldicciomalopremium.WordListActivity.getFileList(WordListActivity.java:541)

Comment: That's usually thrown when there are invalid characters in a filename. There might be an issue with your parsing. What's "values?"

Comment: You have the permission for android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in manifest?

Comment: the permission is there in the manifest. The filename is of the format 1375701341.3gp

Comment: Okay, I have something. Instead of getExternalFilesDir(null), try Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(). It probably won't make a difference but... Worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

add this permission to Your manifest file

Answer (score 0):

add WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE PERMISSION in your manifest file